# How can i access AdminDirectory.Users.list() after deploying gmail addon?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, gmail-addons

I have a gmail addon in which i am accessing all the domain users using **AdminDirectory.Users.list()** During development i added this through resources -> advanced google services and enabled it. after deploying the application to marketplace i am not able to access this data.

I have enabled admin sdk from cloud platform libraries. but still not able to access it. It would be great if someone can suggest what to do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by "not being able to access"? Do you mean it's a permission issue? Or is it not finding the AdminDirectory function?

Comment: my app was failing when i call that function. its giving some permission error.

Comment: Check the scopes in the Oauth 2.0 scopes section of the [G Suite Marketplace SDK](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/sdk). You should have the [user.readonly or user](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list#auth) scopes.

Comment: I am trying to call user list api which is [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list). i have given the required scopes in my application and i have created api key for my application. but how can i get access-token to call this api from my gmail addon?

Comment: when try to call this api from google console it is working and i am getting the required the data. but when i try to call from my gmail addon app then i didnt understand where to get the access token from. can someone help me?